# Visual Studio is thinking a form as a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I did unfortunately deleted my form by mistake and it was no longer available. But when I recovered it from Recuva software, it was added to the visual studio but **the designer view** is unavailable and it is taking the `Form` as a simple `class`. Why is it doing then?

Comment: A Form is a class. If you lost the designer file you will have to recreate the Form. I encourage you to use source control.

Comment: A Form has [multiple files associated with it](https://imgur.com/kykkUX8).  Did you recover all of  them?

Comment: After the restore do you have your designer and eventually the resource file with the same name as the form file correctly nested under the form.cs main file?

Answer (score 0):

That's because forms rely on a resource file and designer.cs file that get executed during initialize component at compile time.  Your designer view relies on these files to generate the form within the designer view.  If you delete the form, these files get deleted with it.  You would have to either restore the resource files associated with the original form, or right click on your main solution, and create a new form.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the item in the `.csproj` file does not reference the file as a form.

A very simple way without any manual code is to create a new form with the same name, and copy all code from the original one to the new one.

Comment: Thanks, I found your answer helpful! It did worked!